# Calculate between which two numbers of a series zero lies, and by how much?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

First off, please forgive / correct me on any errors in terminology and so forth.

I want to be able to find the position of zero within a series. For a simple linear series like this:

```
[-0.85, -0.65, -0.45, -0.25, -0.05, 0.15, 0.35, 0.55]
```

It is intuitively clear that zero lies 1/4 of the way between -0.05 and 0.15. From here, we can easily calculate its fractional / normalised position (0.0 to 1.0) in the total series.

For non-linear series, having values negative through positive, how do we calculate where 0 lies? Or at the very least, how far between two of its nearest neighbours it lies?

Comment: It sounds like you expect to be able to have some unambiguous function $f$ such that $f(1),f(2),f(3),\dots$ give the values in the sequence you provide and you want to extend this function such that it accepts any real inputs and ask what value(s) of $x$ they are such that $f(x)=0$.  "*For non-linear series...*"  Why should you expect there to be an unambiguous way to find such a function $f$?

Comment: This is not clear.  If you have information regarding the non-linear series then you can (possibly) use that.  But, if we are, say, given the sequence $[1,1,1,\cdots, 1, 1, 1]$ we can't tell whether the underlying function is identically $1$ or if it is equal to $\sin (\pi x)$, for example.

Comment: If you knew ahead of time that the function must be linear, then yes we can find an unambiguous $f$ satisfying the conditions (*if such an $f$ existed in the first place*), or if it were quadratic, etc... but such restrictions must be explicitly stated.  If you give no restrictions whatsoever then there is no hope of getting an unambiguous answer.  You could try to use [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation), a sort of "playing connect the dots" approach, to come up with a guesstimate for what you want, but it by no means needs to be correct.

Comment: Thanks all, I had wondered if that was the case and you've confirmed it. That suffices for me.